# what is the best way using loop in Jquery with tables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery and I want to know how can loop in the table using each() and the result even I get all input text in every cell or get the last input for every cell function, see pic:

[image: This is pic how I try to do it]

```
<h3>Input Table</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Number">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Number">
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<h3>OutPut Table</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td>First Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
            <td>Second Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
            <td>Second Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
$("tr").has("td").each(function () {

    $("input").val($(this));

    });

$("td").each(function () {

    $("input").var($(this));
});

$("input").val($("td").text());
```

It has to be a method for that I'm sure but I don't know how
I'm appreciated for your help
thanks in advance.

Comment: You should share the code of what you tried instead of an image.

Comment: Thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: You may want to upvote any helpful answer. (It's strange to see an accepted with score 0. :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to copy the value of the `input`s of the first table to the `html` of the other table.
I can't say if it's the best one, but it's working, and it's pretty short!

Check the snippet:

```js
$("#in").on('keyup change', function() {

  // Gets all the inputs in 1st table
  var ins = $("#in td input");

  // Gets all the tds in the 2nd table and do for each
  $("#out td").each(function(index) {
    // Fills the "html" of the output with the "val" of the input
    $(this).html($(ins[index]).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Input Table</h3>
<table id="in" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Number">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Second Name">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Second Number">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h3>OutPut Table</h3>
<table id="out" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
    <td>Second Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
    <td>Second Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Be sure to analyze and decompose the code to understand it, I've commented it.

You'll have to stylize a little the tables with CSS so that the output table doesn't autofit everytime we change the inputs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much
That was very Useful ^_^
i was wonder can it be done with each() because it's represent the loop function in jquery

Comment: @MrWebDev You're right, I modified it with `.each()`. It's shorter than before! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, you can solve this below one of the way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var table = $("table.input-table tbody");

  table.find('tr').each(function (key, val) {
      $(this).find('td').each(function (k, input) {
          var content = $(this).find('input').val();
          $("table.output-table tbody tr:eq("+k+") td:eq("+key+")").html(content)
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Input Table</h3>
    <table border="1" class="input-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="First Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Number" value="First Number">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Name" value="Second Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Number" value="Second Number">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
<h3>OutPut Table</h3>
    <table border="1" class="output-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
          </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
        <tr>
            <td>First Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
            <td>Second Name Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
            <td>Second Number Should<br /> Appeared Here</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: obviously js is Awesome like you ^_^
it's a little bit shorter :d
Thank you so much